# Join a value onto an existing data.table without an exact match (matching within an interval)

Tags: r, join, vlookup, fuzzyjoin

I have a column in a data.table `(DT1)` that is a decreasing count (let's say `pol_count`), and another column for the average age in a population (say `AverageAge`). I am trying to take my value of `pol_count` (say 400) and my value of `AverageAge` (say 85) and match them to an interval within a table called `FactorFile`.

Here is a glimpse of `FactorFile`:

```
Count_Greater_Than  Age_Less_Than   Months  Factor
100                 80              12      1
85                  82              16      0.85
65                  84              20      0.65
45                  86              24      0.45
```

In this instance, `pol_count` is > 100 so it would return the third column's (`Months`) value of 12, and `AverageAge` is < 86 but > 84 so it would return 20. I then need another column to take the max, so final answer is 20. Finally, a column for the `Factor` associated with 20 which is 65%.

I'm not sure how to join on a table without using exact matches. Basically I want a VLOOKUP with the last argument as TRUE, to pull the closest value to the supplied lookup value.

I've tried using the package `fuzzyjoin`, here is my statement. It runs, but nothing seems to happen to my data.table:

```
fuzzy_left_join(DT1, FactorFile, by = c("AverageAge" = "Average_Age_Less_Than"), match_fun = `<=`)
```

Any tips on how to use fuzzyjoin correctly or an easier way to make this join happen? To summarize, I'm trying to take two columns in DT1, and return both a Months column and Factor column onto DT1, by joining on FactorFile.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of those, could you please expand?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
DT1[, c("M1", "F1") := 
    FactorFile[.SD, on=.(Count_Greater_Than=pol_count), roll=Inf, .(Months, Factor)]
]

DT1[, c("M2", "F2") := 
    FactorFile[.SD, on=.(Age_Less_Than=AverageAge), roll=Inf, .(Months, Factor)]
]

DT1[, c("M", "Fac") := {
        mm <- pmax(M1, M2)
        .(mm, fifelse(mm==M1, F1, F2))
    }]
```

output:

```
   pol_count AverageAge M1 F1 M2   F2  M  Fac
1:       400         85 12  1 20 0.65 20 0.65
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(pol_count=400, AverageAge=85)
FactorFile <- fread("
Count_Greater_Than  Age_Less_Than   Months  Factor
100                 80              12      1
85                  82              16      0.85
65                  84              20      0.65
45                  86              24      0.45")
```